# c# XElement linq, return bool

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml

I need to return bool type from a field that contains 1 or 0

```
<auto>1</auto>
```

Code

```
    public bool GetBooksAuto()
    {
        return (bool)xd.Elements("root").Elements("books").Elements("auto")
            .Select(x => x)
            .Any();
    }
```

Can be written in one return line or should I test strings for 1 and 0.
Thank you!

Comment: This is already a oneliner... I don't understand your question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to check whether any of `auto` elements has value `1`:

```
xd.Elements("root").Elements("books").Elements("auto")
    .Select(a => (int)a == 1) // here you get true if value is 1 and false if 0
    .Any()
```

You can put condition directly into `Any` operator:

```
xd.Elements("root").Elements("books").Elements("auto").Any(a => (int)a == 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
return xd.Elements("root").Elements("books").Elements("auto")
                      .FirstOrDefault() != null;
```